# Don't open app when call reportOutgoingCall in CallKit?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I have a simple code

```
  let uuid = UUID()

  let provider = CXProvider(configuration: CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "My App"))
  provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
  provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: uuid, startedConnectingAt: nil)

  let controller = CXCallController()
  let transaction = CXTransaction(action: CXStartCallAction(call: uuid, handle: CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: "Pete Za")))
  controller.request(transaction, completion: { error in
    if error == nil {
      print("CXStartCallAction")
    } else {
      print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "??")
    }
  })

  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 5) {
    print("reportOutgoingCall  -- connectedAt")
    provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: uuid, connectedAt: nil)
  }
```

It is that ok.

But when I minimize app and call func `provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: uuid, connectedAt: nil)` my app open.

How to don't open my app after minimize app and call `provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: uuid, connectedAt: nil)`

[image]

Comment: Try using an if statement. ( if there is an outgoing call { Terminate application} )

Answer (score 0):

Check if your app is running in the background. And if it isn't then try terminating the app in "View did disappear".